# Are there any major advantages to Upgrading Silverlight from 2 to 3?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight

Is it worth updating a Silverlight 2 project to Silverlight 3? Or should I just wait for four.

We currently have several Silverlight 2 projects in a web application and would like to know if there are benifits.

So far I have this:

Moonlight(silverlight for linux) only supports V2

quite a few code changes in the projects I have which would require

Comment: I currently use this to switch between projects

http://blogs.msdn.com/amyd/archive/2009/03/18/switching-from-silverlight-3-tools-to-silverlight-2-tools.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend switching to SL4 if you want many advanced features which are present in a traditional desktop Application. Some of them are

- You can have better `clipboard` support -- I just heard about it, have to check it out
- Printing support will be added. At present it is not there
- At present if you try to scroll a `DataGrid` using your mouse ball, it doesn't work. It is there in SL4
- You can create `right-click` menus to handle right-clicks. Reminds you of desktop apps?
- You need `Microphone` access? Or `webcam` access? At present Flash can do it but Silverlight cannot. It is there in upcoming SL4
- I heard that `RichTextArea` is also coming. I need to confirm this and tell
- Somone I know was talking about support for codecs like `H.264`! Since Microsoft has paid the royalty for H.264 to `MPEG LA`, they can probably think of putting it inside Silverlight 4 for streaming videos. My 2 cents :)
- Probably they are giving some more enhancement in DataGrid apart from mouse-wheel. Let's see.

Apart from that as far as I remember from the Silverlight 4 beta announcements, can anyone confirm?

- Notification API
- COM Support
- Better themeing support
- Drag and Drop

Probably the list is endless.

OTOH if you want a list of what's new in Silverlight 3, you probably need to read the release notes or here are a few things, I have no idea if you need them or not.

- `NetworkStatus` API to check if network is available or not. i.e. Connected/Disconnected
- It can use `GPU` to relieve your CPU from the heavy stress
- If you want to make beautiful UIs, then `Pixel Shader` can come to your use.
- I have never tried, but heard that there is `Perspective 3D` support too.

Comment: thank you for your response, per your post I do not see any reason to upgrade just yet, will reconsider when four comes out. I do also like the sandbox in version 4. I am justy scared by upgrading i will have issues with other OSes and browsers where 2.0 seems pretty compatible.

Comment: Also remember that the client needs to run Silverlight 4 runtime to be able to use all these things. The biggest challenge as of now. Silverlight is evolving pretty fast which can be problematic for clients too. Anyway there is always a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a LOB application then Silverlight 3 or 4 are worth switching to. If Moonlight is important to you then I would go for Silverlight 3 now rather than waiting for Silverlight 4 because you are likely to get the Moonlight support sooner.

Comment: Sorry i just don't see any features here worth upgrading to